# Google Drive stored HTML file as gDoc file, how to get original HTML file back?

Tags: html, drive

I backed up HTML file to Google Drive and when I downloaded it, it's now a gDoc file. I no longer have the original files so now it's wrapped in this gDoc file. I have tried to export using **File > Download > Web page (.html, zipped)** however, it just downloads an HTML file which is a view of how Google Docs is rendering the document, rather than the original HTML file.

Is there a way to retrieve the original file?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I open the file in Google Docs and view the Version History, I can find the initial upload: "Imported .html file - **View original**"

Clicking View original allows me to see that HTML file and download it.